# Mysqli PHP Query Count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

How can I can I query this and get this kind of result Toyota (3)?
This is my database structure.

```
Make   | Model | Total Cars |

Toyota | Vios  |  1         |

Toyota | Hilux |  2         |
```

Comment: yes sir I already use the distinct and I get now the Toyota. What my problem is how to count

Comment: Answer posted assuming that is your actual DB structure.

Comment: Actually you are looking for sum not count. Am I right?

Comment: @chris85 *Aye, y'aye*, [and he just keeps going, and going...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41798350/)

Comment: Haha @Fred-ii- I havent seen the bunny in a while. The OP actually has +3 questions on the same topic, :(. Probable XY question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` with `group by` to calculate the inventory of a specific make.

```
select sum(totalcars) from cars group by make
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6503/1

To include the `make` add it to the `select` query:

```
select sum(totalcars), make from cars group by make
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6503/2

Comment: Wondering when this one will go green ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select `Make`, sum(`Total Cars`) from table_name group by `Make`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this query :

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM tableName WHERE Make='Toyota'
```

If you want to display all Makes woth count then

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM tableName Group By Make
```

Comment: Question seems looking for sum not for count.