# mysql query PHP: I want to a specific items to be first and can modify the query how many items to be displayed

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table below.

```
id  | car_name | owner
-------------------------
1   | Toyota   | Jan
2   | Ford     | Mike
3   | Isuzu    | Andrew
4   | BMW      | Jan
5   | Ferrari  | Steve
6   | Audi     | Jan
7   | Benz     | Kin
8   | Hyundai  | Jan
9   | Kia      | Jan
```

I want to get all the car owners, but if Jan has 5 or more cars I can modify the query and get the first four item of Jan to be in the list. I don't care about the order that I receive the rest of the items. My priority is Jan should be the first.

```
id  | car_name | owner
-------------------------
1   | Toyota   | Jan
4   | BMW      | Jan
7   | Benz     | Jan
8   | Hyundai  | Jan
2   | Ford     | Mike
3   | Isuzu    | Andrew
5   | Ferrari  | Steve
6   | Audi     | Bob
```

Comment: What if someone else has 5 or more cars?

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: `... ORDER BY FIELD(owner,'Jan') ...`

Comment: My only priority to be the first on the list is Jan.

Comment: @JohnConde it's also a repost and no idea why it got an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enumerate the values, and variables are the simplest way.  Then, an additional join gives you the information you need to order by the most frequent names in the table:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@n = name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@rn := name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @n := '', @rn := 0
      order by name
     ) t join
     (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by name
     ) tn
     on t.name = tn.name
where rn <= 4
order by cnt desc, name;
```

Comment: can I ask for a Jfiddle for it sir?